# matlab meshgrid parameter meaning confused

Tags: matlab

```
[X,Y] = meshgrid(-2:.2:2, -4:.4:4);
```

When I print the X and the X is 21*21 double.

I did not find any hint about the 21  in the meshgrid parameter, how it get the 21?

Can somebody help to explain it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

21 is the size of `-2:.2:2` and of `-4:.4:4`. In general, `[X,Y] = meshgrid(a,b)` returns matrices `X`, `Y` of size `length(b)`x`length(a)`.

A simpler example:

```
[X,Y] = meshgrid([1 2 3], [1 2]);
```

gives `X` and `Y` of size 2x3.

Comment: can you explain why the "-2:.2:2" 's size if 21? Is any example of this usage?

Comment: `-2:.2:2` is a vector defined as: begin at `-2` and increment by `.2` until reaching (no larger than) `2`. So it has 21 elements: `-2`, `-1.8`, `-1.6`, ..., `2`.

Comment: @user1279988 This statement means from -2 to 2 take a number every 0.2 and including both ends. You can see this is essentially: `-2, -1.8, ... 1.8, 2`

Comment: Just to clarify: in general, first end is always included, but last end may not be included (for example in `-2:.3:2`)